# SQL select results and use them as for array in update statement

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to select 4 random names from my sql database. I need these 4 name to be updated in a update statement. I am trying to do this with a for statement but this is not working.

Question: How do i select random results limited to 4 in this case and use the results to up date the database table with just those 4 results in the where statement. I need to get the names seperate from the update to run a query on them in a later stadion.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id,naam,geld,slapped,slaptime,lastbananacrime,banana_safe FROM gebruikers WHERE geld > 50000 AND naam NOT IN (?) 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$usernamesession);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$data = $result->fetch_array();


for($i=0;$i<count($data['id']);$i++){
    $target = $data['naam'][$i];

$stmt8 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE gebruikers SET geld = geld + trim(?), lastbananacrime = NOW()
WHERE naam = ? ");
$stmt8->bind_param("ss", $bananasstolerounded,$target);
$stmt8->execute();
```

Comment: Anyone else that has a suggestion how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of an SQl database is that many operations that would require iterating over recordsets in PHP can be delegated to the database as a single query.

Here, you're selecting names at random then iterating over that set to apply the updates individually. With a proper UPDATE  query there's no need for the separate operations:

```
$stmt8 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE gebruikers 
    SET geld = geld + trim(?),
    lastbananacrime = NOW() 
    WHERE geld > 50000 AND naam NOT IN (?) 
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4");

$stmt8->bind_param("ss", $bananasstolerounded,$usernamesession);
$stmt8->execute();
```

It's not clear how you're generating the target list for `naam`. It's likely that an extension to this query will do that for you too.

Comment: Thanks. That way i can update 4 random names. I am trying to generate the list with the select query. I need it separate because i use the 4 random names in a later stadion. So the update wont give me the names that where updated?

Comment: @newusertomysqli12 It's true that this won't return the names for you. If that's important this approach might not be for you. You've only shown a small part of your code though, so there might be other ways to achieve things that don't involve iterating over a recordset.

Comment: Thanks for the reaction. At the moment this is the only code i wrote to achieve this. I am trying to generate the random list of 4 with this query. When done i want to use those names in more querys, for example the update one i posted. So i am searching for a way to get those 4 names stored in variables so i can work with them. Sorry for being unclear. Anyone knows how to aproach ?